# Access _MobileSubscription in child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

We have an SMS shortcode that is provisioned in the Parent BU and in the Child BU.

Unfortunately, the unknown/default message is only configurable in the Parent BU.

```
%% SET @status = Lookup('_MobileSubscription','_OptInStatusID','_MobileNumber',MOBILE_NUMBER)=%%
```

This should work, however, it returns nothing.  We believe it is because it is looking in the Parent _MobileSubscription.  How can we tell it to look the status up in the Child _MobileSubscription?

Ultimately we are trying to use AMPscript to tailor the unknown message based upon the status of the Mobile Number.  I am guessing if the SMS shortcode was only in the Child BU this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to contact support for this.

There's a setting that defines which business unit has the **ownership** of the short/long code - this will let you define the unknown / default messages in your desired BU (and only there).

There's also **inheritance** which I assume is enabled in your account at the time. Phone numbers from the parent BU are "inherited" by all child BUs. This setting would need to be disabled and the ownership needs to be assigned to your child BU.

If you want the phone number to also be available in other BUs, ask support to **share** the phone number to the BUs you want.

So to sum up, ask support to:

- disable the inheritance of the phone number
- change the ownership to the target BU
- list the business units (MIDs) to which the phone number should be shared to

Comment: If the shortcode is used in more than one BU it is always owned by the EID, you can not change this

Comment: @EazyE The "ownership" understood as on which BU you can change the error messages, can be changed - this is something I had to request from support as well and now don't have the option to configure those messages in the root BU.

Comment: Understood. But if it’s shared in multiple BU the default message is owned by the EID and can not be changed. If the short code is used in ONLY 1 BU any BU can be the owner

Comment: Ultimately we had to just not use it in more than one BU...